# How to reuse form and actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm building a subscription service. Members log in by entering their cellphone number. If there's a match, we send an SMS with a code that they insert on the page, and if that's OK, they're logged in.

Now, we wan't to reuse that when users (not necessarily logged in members) are making subscriptions on other products. So when they've selected a product we wan't them to enter cellphone and SMS-code to proceed.

My question is how I can reuse that without duplicating it?

Right now it's located at `/account/login (index.cshtml, index.cshtml.cs)` and the new part will probably be on `/subscription/start (index.cshtml, index.cshtml.cs)`.

I know that I can use a `Partial View` or `View Component`, but that's only for the view. How can I do so that I don't need to have the actions in both index.cshtml.cs's?

My current form:

```
@model Models.SMSVerification

<div class="grid space-around">
    <div class="griditem no-padding col-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-container">
                @if (Model?.Cellphone == null)
                {
                    <div class="form-group modern">Enter your cellphone number.</div>
                    <div class="form-group modern">
                        <label asp-for="Cellphone"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Cellphone" class="input" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Cellphone"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group buttons">
                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="SendSMS" class="btn secondary">Send SMS</button>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="form-group modern">Enter the code you received on SMS.</div>
                    <div class="form-group modern">
                        <label asp-for="SMSCode"></label>
                        <input asp-for="SMSCode" value="@Model.SMSCode" class="input" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="SMSCode"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group buttons">
                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Verify" class="btn secondary">Login</button>
                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="SendSMS" class="btn secondary clean">Send again</button>
                    </div>
                    <input asp-for="Cellphone" type="text" />
                    <input asp-for="Verification" type="text" value="@Model.Verification" />
                }
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use view components, it's not only for the view, view component has a class where you can write the logic you want and call it any where. see the doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Yes, I know, but the view component can't handle form posts, right?

Comment: thats rigth but you can make an action that manage the post and is that one single action call every time you post from any where in your app

Comment: You mean an action in a controller?

Comment: yes, you can create a controller with only that action

Comment: Also when using RazorPages? I've created `Controllers/SMSVerificationController.cs` and in it `public IActionResult SendSMS() {}` and I have `asp-controller="SMSVerification" asp-action="SendSMS"` but all that happens is a page refresh. When I see the source form action is empty.

Comment: I can post to the controller/action now. I thought I could put the asp-action on the submit-button, but it only works when in the form-tag(?). Could you tell me how to get back to the right view after posting, as `return View(SMSVerification)` isn't the right one - and keeping ModelState?